# replace number at the end of url with incremented value

Tags: javascript

I need to match and replace the number at the end of the url with an incremented value.

```
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/abc/14/"
```

output

```
result = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/abc/15/"
```

I know there are many similar questions like this on stackoverflow but none of them worked for me as they had digits only once in the string while in my case its present multiple times throughout the string.

I tried this

```
   newUrl = existingUrl.replace(/abc\/[0-9]+/g, function(match, number) {
    return parseInt(number)+1;
    });
```

Comment: Could you just turn up the brightness of your screen a little? It's a bit difficult to see the code you've *already tried*...

Comment: I have personally posted to you a response previously. Did you read my code ??

Comment: @kevin, where have you posted it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
var result = url.replace(/(\d+)\/$/, function(x){ return parseInt(x, 10) + 1 + '/' })
```

or with [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) :

```
var result = url.replace(/(\d+)\/$/, x => parseInt(x) + 1 + '/' )
```